# Chinese characters in blog URLs with Apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

A client would like to have Traditional Chinese characters in their blog URLs to help with SEO in Hong Kong, like this:
`example.com.hk/blog/於本網站核`

I have enabled the internationalisation plugin on the server and re-enterd the blog name as the URL and we get the result:
`example.com.hk/blog/guo-tai-ji-gang-long-jian-xi-ji-shi-pei-xun-ji-hua`

I am finding it hard to find relevant information, and the closest I can get is assuming it is done through the .htaccess file? Would `mod_rewrite` know how to change the characters to the right language with the plugin installed?

We are using PerchCMS for the website, and according to the technical support it cannot be done through that.